# How to change the state of a component in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am writing an application which includes authentication of the user. 
If the user has successfully logged in the navbar will show his username
or it will be the default Login/Signup button.
I'm able to achieve this partially. After i login successfully and it redirects to my homepage component, the navbar doesn't show my username but when i refresh the page it shows my username.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

This is my app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

This is my navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg shadow">
  <img class="navbar-dark" src="../../assets/images/ACADEMY.png" alt="devsmen academy logo">
  <button class="navbar-toggler remove-border" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-navbar" aria-controls="collapse-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          (click)="isCollapsed =  !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="isCollapsed">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-navbar" [ngbCollapse] = "isCollapsed">
    <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active text-dark" routerLink=""><b>Home</b>
        <span class="sr-only">Home</span>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" routerLink="academy-home"><b>Academy</b></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" routerLink=""><b>CodeWars</b></a> <!-- We don't have a component for codewars-->
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" routerLink="team-page"><b>Team</b></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" routerLink="blog-page"><b>Blog</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nav" *ngIf="!hasLoggedIn">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" routerLink="sign-in">Login</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" routerLink="sign-up"> SignUp</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nav" *ngIf="hasLoggedIn">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" [routerLink]="route">{{ username }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is my navbar.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../services/users/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public isCollapsed = true;
  @Input() private hasLoggedIn = false;
  @Input() private route;
  @Input() private username;
  constructor(private service: UserService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    // check if the user has logged in
    if ( localStorage.getItem('userid') !== null) {
      this.hasLoggedIn = true;
      this.route = 'profile/' + localStorage.getItem('userid');
      // check if username exists local
      if ( localStorage.getItem('username') === null ) {
        // this creates a new item and stores it in localStorage
        this.service.getUserById(localStorage.getItem('userid')).subscribe( res => {
          localStorage.setItem('username', res.username);
        });
      }
    }
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('username');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that after authentication you're still in Angular Zone?

Comment: ngOnInit, as its name indicates, is called when the component is initialized. Since you log in after, the logged in flag stays false. Read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service: you need to emit an event after login to notify the navbar that a login happened

Comment: Here, the components are not parent and child components, so I think mission control would not work

Answer (score 1):

You can save you user object (id, username, first_name, last_name ...) in localStorage as JSON format and below is example:

login.component.ts

```
    login() {
      this.service.login(user_name, password).subscript(
        (res: any) => {
          localStorage.setItem('userProfile', JSON.stringify(res.user));
        }
      );
    }
```

navbar.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.user = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('userProfile'));
 }
```

navbar.component.html

```
{{user.first_name}}
{{user.last_name}}
```

Comment: That would work and is practical. But maybe you should create and inject a service to wrap those operations, as well as do some routing in case the user is not logged in or the token has expired.